# How can I use cloth simulation to make a chair cushion with buttons?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm struggling to model the cushion for this chair. I have been trying using the cloth simulation to get the cushion+wrinkles, however, I'm unable to achieve a satisfying result with the buttons by using the pinning vertices. And if I level down the specific pinned vertices, I don't get many wrinkles...

Already tried changing vertex mass, increasing pressure, stiffness of vertices...

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19IPBr9BeUQxEOcrCTwXFeSU9bVpxAtyU/view?usp=sharing

Any idea/suggestions on how would you tackle this issue?

[image]

**1) Pins Location**
[image]

**2) Cloth Simulation Config**

[image]

3. End result with equally leveled vertices and using pinning
   [image]
4. End result with lowered z-level pinned vertices (not many wrinkles as reference photo)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I Feel like I've made some noticeable progress here.
The answer is tweaking the Shrinking Factor, under Shape tab.

[image]